# How to display a growing archive of audio files on a website?

Tags: python, html, audio

I'm working on a project (mainly for learning purposes). I have 200+ audio recordings (.mp3) that are currently stored on an Amazon S3 server. I am planning to create some more audio recordings. These are lecture recordings, so they each have a title and a description; some belong to series.

Anyway, I would like to display these recordings on a website. I would like them to show up by date, but I'd also want users to be able to search by name or filter by lecture series.

Being new to this, I just need direction for how to go about doing this. (I have learned the basics of HTML5, CSS, JS, and Python, but I know I have a lot more to learn. So it'd be great if the answers pointed me toward something within those.)

Do I...

- hardcode the pages? Creating series pages and a "View All" page?
- add the lecture information to a sql database and write a script to interact with it?
- something else?

As you can tell, I'm new to all of this, but if someone could point me towards a workable solution so I know what to study, I would appreciate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using http://listjs.com/ it looks like it does what you want in the front end in JS.

If you want to run the back end in python try looking at python-flask or at the django python project. They also support interacting with a database.

As 200 files isn't that large you could store them as xml but it is a good idea to use a database. Especially if you are keen to learn about these things.

There isn't really a right way to do something like this as there are so many.